# Pass in df and column in custom function R

Tags: r, function, gsub

Im looking to apply multiple `gsub` calls on a same df. So, I want to create a function, but doesn't seem to be working. Here is what I got:

```
get_clean_party <- function(df, feature){
  df$feature <- gsub("D","Democrat", df$feature)
  df$feature <- gsub("R","Republican", df$feature)
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are performing an exact match you can use `dplyr`'s `recode` function. Also never use `$` when you have column name as variable.

```
get_clean_party <- function(df, feature){
  df[[feature]] <- dplyr::recode(df[[feature]], D = 'Democrat', R = 'Republican')
  df
}
df <- get_clean_party(df, "col_name")
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work if you pass the column name as a *string*:

```
get_clean_party <- function(df, feature) {
    df[[feature]] <- gsub("D", "Democrat",   df[[feature]])
    df[[feature]] <- gsub("R", "Republican", df[[feature]])
    return(df)
}
```

**Data and Usage:**

```
df <- data.frame(v1=c("R", "D", "R", "D"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df <- get_clean_party(df, "v1")
df

          v1
1 Republican
2   Democrat
3 Republican
4   Democrat
```

Note that we use the double bracket notation to access the data frame column.  The `$` notation wont' work with a variable containing a string column name.